# longest common subsequence among rows of 2D metrics

Tags: recursion, dynamic

Given a matrix **A** of **M** rows and **N** columns of integers, find the length of longest common subsequence among rows of matrix.
**Constraints:**
1 < M, N < 10^5
1 < A[I][J] < 10^7
ex:

```
A = [[4,5,1,2,3], [1,2,3,6,7]]
subsequences among rows
subsequences are:
[],
[1,2],
[1,2,3]
longest and common among both are [1,2,3] should return **3 as length**.
```

how to solve it?

Comment: Metrics? Matrix? And A[i] is just a vector.

Comment: consider it 2-d array or matrix